# What is the difference between `this` and `ActivityClass.this` in android intent constructor?

Tags: java, android, mobile

What is the difference between `this` and `ActivityClass.this` when you pass in to intent constructor

for example given 2 activities: ActivityOne and ActivityTwo

the following doesn't work (compile error)

```
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = null;
            Log.i(TAG, this.toString());
            Log.i(TAG, ActivityOne.this.toString());
            intent = new Intent(this, ActivityTwo.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
```

while this works

```
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = null;
            Log.i(TAG, this.toString());
            Log.i(TAG, ActivityOne.this.toString());
            intent = new Intent(ActivityOnethis, ActivityTwo.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
```

The logging info from the log is

```
activitylab.ActivityOne$1@41fc5818
activitylab.ActivityOne@41fa2948
```

although they are different, but the common answer for passing activity is usually using `this`, I am not why I am running into this problem

Comment: This is basic java.In intent first param is Context.You are using it in your OnClick and passing this,means it will point to your onclick not your class as it is in OnCLick block.Adding class name before this ensures it takes the context of your activity and not your method.

Comment: I guess this will give you the solution. Try this.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18941007/difference-between-myactivity-this-myactivity-class-this

Comment: You have to use YourActivity.this reference in overridden methods only this which taken inner reference instead class.

Answer (score 7):

I'm assuming that your `onClick` method is inside an anonymous class instance (though you didn't include the full code, the `ActivityOne$1` output you see when printing `this` is how anonymous inner classes are displayed), so this refers to the anonymous inner class instance, and not the `ActivityOne` instance containing this instance.

`ActivityOne.this` returns a reference to the containing `ActivityOne` instance, which is what you are supposed to pass to the `Intent` constructor.

Answer (score 1):

This is basic Java and is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5666134/what-is-the-difference-between-class-this-and-this-in-java).

To recap, you can use `Class.this` to reference an instance of a class when it is not visible with a bare `this`, for example from inner classes. In your `onClick` example `this` will refer to an anonymous instance of the `Listener` you are using, while `ActivityOne.this` will refer to the `ActivityOne` instance containing the listener.

Answer (score 0):

ActivityOne.this == Refrence to context

ActivityTwo.class == Reference to class, this is its class name

this == It is Current Type, If you are in Thread then it is Thread Type; if you are in Activity then it is Activity Type; if you are in your custom class then it is type of that particular custom class

When you do the this then you get an error because you must not be in main thread in this you can use getApplicationContext()

When you use myActivity.this It Knows that it will be started from this activitie's context.

Comment: Instead of copy-paste given reference to ans.